# GAE/Python request forwarding?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request, forwarding

I was wondering if there's a pythonic equivalent of the RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response) that I'm used to from Java servlet programming? It's a common enough technique in Java, and enables you to do, say, a little preprocessing of a particular type of request, and then hand over to another url handler. This all happens inside the server, which is an enormous time saver.

The nearest thing I can see in the GAE/Python documentation is RequestHandler.redirect(), but that's hopeless. For one thing, there's an extra round trip to the browser. For another, there's no guarantee the redirect will actually be followed once it's out of my hands, which makes me a little twitchy. (Semantically it's just wrong too, since a redirect implies that the original resource may be unavailable or have moved, which ain't the case.)

There's something that sounds tantalisingly close in webapp2, described at http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RedirectHandler; but from what I can guess from the rather sketchy documentation, it's just for doing a kind of url-rewriting, which is not at all what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about GAE, but in django you can do something like this:

```
def view2(request):
   do_some_stuff()

def view1(request):
    do_some_stuff()
    view2(request) # <-- note this line
```

In GAE maybe you can do this:

```
return View.action.__func__(self, ...)
```

(though this, depending on the function, might screw things up, if, for example, `View.action` uses `self.something_which_should_be_here_but_isnt_because_self_is_some_other_thing`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is simply to refactor the relevant code into a function that you call from both handlers, or to put the functionality in a base class both handlers extend. Which is more suitable depends on your app.